# Installation error with usb flash drive

Tags: 11.04, installation

After booting from usb from flash drive, loading gets freezed. And after sometime an error is displayed..."unable to find medium containing a live file system"..
what i have to do next? 
the os presently using is windows 7 ultimate with 5 partition and processor is corei3.

pls help....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, did you check the md5 of the ISO you downloaded?

Grab a checker, https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM#MD5SUM_on_Windows

compare it to the md5sum for your ISO file here http://releases.ubuntu.com/oneiric/MD5SUMS

if it matches then great.  what tool did you use to make the usb ? this one?
http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3

format the stick, make another and when you boot it, at the boot prompt, choose verify installation media and it will perform md5 checks on the files.